# Does the dealloc in Appdelegate calls or not?

Tags: objective-c

I the allocated arrays in the didFinishLaunching of my appdelegate.And I released those arrays in  the dealloc of the appdelegate.

My doubt here is does the dealloc of appdelegate calls?and does the arrays in the appdelegate releases or not?

Anyone's help will be much appreciated.

Thank you,
Monish Kumar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app delegate is released before the program ends. You can put the release code in the applicationWillTerminate method if you're doubt.

To be sure you can put an NSLog or a breakpoint in the app delegate's `-dealloc`.

(Even if it's not released, when the program ends, whether the object's retain count is 0 or not they will be forcefully de-allocated (this does not mean `-dealloc` will be called — the memory page is just handed back to the O/S).)

Comment: Yes I kept NSlog and break point to the dealloc  eventhough its no displaying anything and breakpoint is not working.